# Turn Keyboard backlight on ASUS Predator

Tags: keyboard, asus, backlight

Hi I've just made the switch to Ubuntu on an Asus Predator. And loving it so far. However, I'm a command line n00b and I've been trying to get my keyboard backlight to turn on with no success. Could someone please post a step by step "guide" to do this?

I've tried:

```
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

but I just get this back:

```
'/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness': No such file or directory
2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ls /sys/class/leds/*/*bright*`? Probably it has just a slightly different name.

Comment: /sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::numlock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/class/leds/input5::scrolllock/max_brightness

Comment: Okay, doesn't seem like it is controllable through `/sys/class/leds`... Don't know then, mine doesn't have a keyboard backlight.

Comment: That sucks it looked so cool with all the colors when I was running windows but maybe it's not compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try `xset led on` yet? Also do you know the exact keyboard model?

Comment: Yeah I tried xset led on without any luck :(

Comment: I've noticed the backlight works when coming out of sleep mode so there should be a way to turn it on permenantly....